# Проблема с кодировкой при использовании std::filesystem::path

Tags: c++, кодировка

Возникла одна небольшая проблема, когда я делаю вот так, то все хорошо:

```
std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path().parent_path().append("Resources").append("Shaders").string().c_str() << std::endl;
```

В этом случае выводится корректный путь,но стоит мне сделать вот так:

```
std::filesystem::path path = std::filesystem::current_path().parent_path().append("Resources").append("Shaders");
const char* shadersPath = path.string().c_str(); // или u8string().c_str()
std::cout << shadersPath << std::endl;
```

То в результате получаю проблему с кодировкой:

▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌K

В чем может быть данная проблема? Мне нужно получить именно С строку в кодировке ANSI или UTF-8

Comment: А какая система? И что представляет собой `path.string()`?

Comment: Windows 10
Возвращает путь в строковом формате, из документации взял. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path

Comment: Если это Windows то для перевода в utf8 надо будет преобразовать путь из wchar_t при помощи библиотеки ICU или функции `MultibyteToWideChar`. Затем для печати преобразовать путь обратно в wchar_t